# POST request to JIRA REST API to create issue of type Minutes

Tags: perl, jira-rest-api, mojo-useragent

```perl
my $create_issue_json = '{"fields": { "project": { "key": "ABC" }, "summary": "summary for      version 1", "description": "Creating an issue via REST API", "issuetype": { "name": "Minutes" }}}';
$tx1 = $jira_ua->post($url2 => json => decode_json($create_issue_json));
my $res1 = $tx1->res->body;
```

I try to create a jira issue of type Minutes but POST expects some fields which are not available in the issue of type Minutes. The below is the response.

```json
{"errorMessages":["Brands: Brands is required.","Detection: Detection is required."],"errors":{"versions":"Affects Version/s is required.","components":"Component/s is required."}}
```

I also tried to fetch the schema using createMeta api but don't find any useful info. The below is the response from createmeta.

```json
{"maxResults":50,"startAt":0,"total":3,"isLast":true,"values":[
    {
        "self":"https://some_url.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/1",
        "id":"1",
        "description":"A problem which impairs or prevents the functions of the product.",
        "iconUrl":"https://some_url.com:8443/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=25683&avatarType=issuetype",
        "name":"Bug",
        "subtask":false},
    {
        "self":"https://some_url.com:8443/rest/api/2/issuetype/12",
        "id":"12",
        "description":"An issue type to document minutes of meetings, telecons and the like",
        "iconUrl":"https://some_url.com:8443/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=28180&avatarType=issuetype",
        "name":"Minutes",
        "subtask":false
    },
    {
        "self":"https://some_url.com:8443/rest/api/2/issuetype/23",
        "id":"23",
        "description":"Used to split an existing issue of type \"Bug\"",
        "iconUrl":"https://some_url.com:8443/images/icons/cmts_SubBug.gif",
        "name":"Sub Bug",
        "subtask":true
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there Jira Admin has added these as manadatory fields for all the issuetypes which I came to know after speaking with him. He has now individual configuration for different issue types and am able to create minutes.